# Test if two texts are likely to have been written by the same author

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a program that can test if two English-language texts are likely to have been written by the same author. Ideally it should output some confidence score, and indicate in the texts what led the program to believe that two texts are from the same author.

Linux or Windows, CLI or GUI, and gratis if possible. Web service is fine too.